# Script hosting in .Net 4.5

Tags: .net-4.5

We were using IronRuby in our applications for some simple scripting of biz logic and rules.

We are trying to upgrade everything to .NET 4.5 - and our ScriptRuntime/IronRuby code is not happy with that.   It does not lok like IronRuby has had a lot of traction lately, so we are wondering what would be a good scripting engine to switch to that is best supported by a .NET 4.5 environment.  We prefer simple - the less third-party stuff we have to bring in the better.  OUr scripts are also simple - not a big effort to convert.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If converting your scripts to C# isn't a problem, I would recommend looking into the [Microsoft "Roslyn" CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) and its [Scripting API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx).

Because the .NET compiler developers are currently rebuilding their compilers in the Roslyn architecture and the Visual Studio team intends to consume the Roslyn compilers in the future, it's a safe bet that support for this scenario will remain for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking to consume the Roslyn architecture, you could also leverage Windows PowerShell by writing a [custom host application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563.aspx) that can execute PowerShell scripts that contain your business logic.